# How do i set dependency to ForeignKey in my child

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need the id to fetch data collections from my parent.
The plan is to fetch all friends from the repository by using the ParentId.

To illustrate I have a Parent and Child class and also one Mapper each.
I suppose I must define the key in the ParentMapper.

See comment in my code

```
    {
        public class Child {
            public int IdChild { get; set; }
            public string ChildName {get;set;}
            // here is the problem
            //I need to define ParentID as ForeignKey in some way but how??
            //I belive its done in the ParentMapper
            public virtual int ParentId { get; set; } //ForeignKey  

            public virtual ICollection<Friend>   Friends        { get; set; }

            //The plan is to fetch all friends from the repository by using the ParentId and 
            //keep the entity as clean as possible.
            public virtual ICollection<Friend>   FamilyFriends  { get; set; }
        }
        public class Parent {
            public int IdParent { get; set; }
            public string ParentName {get;set;}

            public virtual ICollection<Friend>   Friends        { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Child>    Children        { get; set; }
        }
    }


    {
        class ParentMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
        {
            public ParentMapper()
            {
                HasKey(one => one.IdParent);

                //I started out like this but its not possible....
                //But this will give an error obviusly
                HasMany(c => c.Children).WithRequired(d => d.ParentId).HasForeignKey(one => one.ParentId);
            }
        }
    }

    {
        class ChildMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
        {
            public ChildMapper()
            {
                HasKey(one => one.IdChild);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `Parent.Friends` intended to be a mapped collection too? (I.e. does Friend also have a FK to Parent, or only to Child?)

Comment: Hi @Gert Arnold, Good question   :)  well to get to the essens I left it out becouse I do not think its part of the problem, or maybe it is... anyhow, yes it´s intended to be a mapped collection too.

Comment: That would be rather complicated. I'm not sure if you realize the implications. `Friend` would have three FKs (Parent, and two for the two collections in `Child`) that should be nullable and mutually exclusive. (i.e. only one of them can have a value in each record). It would be simpler if a Parent only finds its Friends _through_ its Children.

Comment: If you want I can write this with data annotation))

Comment: Thanks @ Elvin Arzumanoğlu that would be great.

Comment: Please, tell me How is my answer? I can write this with Fluent Api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Child {

        public int ChildId { get; set; }

        public string ChildName {get;set;}

        [ForeignKey("Parent")]
        public int ParentId { get; set; } //ForeignKey  
        public Parent Parent{get; set;}


        public List<Friend>   Friends        { get; set; }

        public List<Friend>   FamilyFriends  { get; set; }
    }
    public class Parent {
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string ParentName {get;set;}

        public List<Friend>   Friends        { get; set; }
        public List<Child>    Children        { get; set; }
    }

    public class Friend
    {
        public int FriendId { get; set; }
        public string FriendName {get;set;}

        [ForeignKey("Parent")]
        public int ParentId{get;set;}
        public Friend Parent {get;set;}

        [ForeignKey("Child")]
        public int ChildId{get;set;}

        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public Child Child {get;set;}

         [ForeignKey("ChildFam")]
        public int ChildFamId{get;set;}

        [InverseProperty("FamilyFriends")]
        public Child ChildFam {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: Some DB support multi relationship, but some don't.

Comment: This is good @Elvin Arzumanoğlu, I will try it out but using a mapper file. And InverseProperty I see is somthing I must make use of. I will get back here after a few days to update my results. Thanks !

Comment: after a few days? :DDDD

Comment: Funny yea, better late then never @Elvin Mammadov , things happend in life that one can not predict, but for the moment I am back.